# Just trying to give a bold font to an input text

Tags: css, input, stylesheet

I'm trying to give a bold font to an input this way below but it doesn't work..

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<style type=”text/css”>

.jander2{

  font-weight: bold;

}

</style>

<form method="post" action="somepage">
        <input id="jander" class="jander2">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `<style>` should be in the `<head>` section:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   .jander2{
     font-weight: bold;
   }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="post" action="somepage">
   <input id="jander" class="jander2">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT:** *To satisfy the commenter*: use only standard double quotes, no curly special quotes as you had in your `<style>` tag.

Comment: @user248959, try the updated code. You had curly braces (`”`) around the `type` attribute in `<style>` tag but you need normal double quotes (`"`). Interestingely the other quotes are ok. What are you using as your code editor?

Comment: Hmm. Two other answers mentioned the curly quotes problem, yet the accepted answer is one that does not (except in a comment), and the accepted answer implies that the problem is the location of the style tag, which is... misleading. :/

Comment: Semantically it dosen't matter - there are many ways to declare your style and both above will work. It only matters regarding good coding practices.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/4rAhy/

Code here:

```
Inline style: <input type="text" style="font-weight: bold;"></input><br />
<style>
.jander2 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style> 
External Style: <input type="text" class="jander2"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Form controls are strange beasts. Some browsers don't let you style them at all, others only let you do a few limited things. Generally, this is because the browser gets the form controls from the operating system, rather than generating them itself.

That said, bold text should certainly be within the realm of attributes you can style. I think the problem is the curly quotes around "text/css" in your style declaration. (Putting the style declaration in the body can be a validation error depending on your doctype, but it should still work.)

Answer (score 0):

This by its self works

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   .jander2{
     font-weight: bold;
   }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="post" action="somepage">
   <input id="jander" class="jander2">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

What I'm thinking is that you have something like

```
input{font-weight: normal;}
```

kicking around in your other CSS. Take a look to see if there is any other CSS that might be overriding `.jander2`

Remember CSS is read top to bottom, so styles that are applied later will override styles that are applied earlier.

Alternatively you can try

```
  <style type="text/css">
   .jander2{
     font-weight: bold !important;
   }
 </style>
```

But this isn't recommended since it just masks the problem.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to cheat, then this is another solution:

```
    <input type='text'  size='35' style='font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;' value = 'Hi'  />
```