# Bold particular text in string on runtime jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

My requirement is : Thers's an input field. When user is going to filled it,
on runtime i searched for #tag and make text bold. And wants to separate both groups of #tags

**For Example:** "I am more #**FromSide** #**FromSide**  and would like to speak with someone more #**ToSide**"
Group1: #**FromSide** #**FromSide**
Group2: #**ToSide**

Here's my code:

```
 `$('#custm-field').keyup(function(){`
            `let str = $(this).val();`
            `let arr = str.split(" ");`
            `$(arr).each((i,e)=>{`
                `if(e=="#")`
                `{ // $(e).css('font-weight','bold');`
                    `arr[i].replace(e,"<strong>"+e+"</strong>");}
                    `let newStr = arr.join(" ");`
            `$('#custm-field').val(newStr)`
            `});`
```

Comment: Can you express the problem you encouter when running this code?

Comment: Onn running this code, not get desired output

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using RegEx:

```js
$('#custm-field').keyup(function(){
  let str = $(this).val();
  str = str.replace(/#(.+?)\s/, '<strong>$1</strong>');
  $('#custm-field').val(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="custm-field"></input>
```

However, the bold effect won't be displayed in input fields, you need a [contenteditable element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) for this.

Comment: Particular code returns output : Hello  <strong>ok</strong> But in my case tags will not visible to user instead innet text of  tag will be bold

Comment: What kind of input field you are using?

Comment: Change my example’s input element to yours and see if it works

Comment: If you are using contenteditables already

Comment: <input type="text" name="custm-field" id="custm-field" placeholder="Type Here..." class="form-control">

Comment: Cuz I don’t hunk there are any input fields with <input> can display HTML styles

Comment: I replaced my input tag with your but result is same

Comment: You need a contenteditable span/div/sth else to apply styles in text input. <input> tag doesn’t provide you a choice to style the text inside using HTML directly. You either need a [contenteditable element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10839422/14595300) or [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10839691/14595300)

Comment: Or maybe have you ran your code successfully before such a bold text is displayed in an input field?

Comment: Nice, glad to hear the problem finally solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've constructed a solution for you,

First of all, you can't add HTML tags inside the value of an input tag. So you have to make use of `contenteditable` HTML attribute, by setting it to true `contenteditable="true"` on any element you can start to edit the content of it (write inside it).

> **NOTE:** I added a background-color to make it visible when its empty

```
<div contentEditable="true" id="text" style="background-color: #eee;"></div>
```

Your JavaScript (JQuery) would look like this:

> Note that your code had many errors I had to fix.

```js
$('#text').keyup(function(){
            // get the div element
            let e = document.querySelector('#text');
            // get only the text inside the element (without the HTML tags)
            let str = e.innerText;
            e.innerHTML = '';
            // create a new element to contain our text because you cant add HTML text inside a DOM element directly
            let tag = document.createElement('div');
            let arr = str.split(" ");
            // this string will contain our HTML and text 
            let newStr = ``;
            $(arr).each((i,e)=>{
                if(e[0]=="#")
                { 
                    newStr += `<strong>${e}</strong>`;
                }
                else{
                    newStr += `${e}`
                }
                newStr += ` `;
            })
            // add the string to the inner HTML of the element we created
            tag.innerHTML = newStr;
            // append the newly created element inside the div
            e.append(tag);

            // based on Vito Gentile answer
            // this is to move the cursor to the end of the text we added, other wise the cursor would be at start of the text
            cursorManager.setEndOfContenteditable(e);
        });
```

I made use of the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19588665/9737883), this is where this line `cursorManager.setEndOfContenteditable(e);` came from. Here is their code for convenience.

```js
(function( cursorManager ) {

            //From: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements
            var voidNodeTags = ['AREA', 'BASE', 'BR', 'COL', 'EMBED', 'HR', 'IMG', 'INPUT', 'KEYGEN', 'LINK', 'MENUITEM', 'META', 'PARAM', 'SOURCE', 'TRACK', 'WBR', 'BASEFONT', 'BGSOUND', 'FRAME', 'ISINDEX'];

            //From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript
            Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
                var i = this.length;
                while (i--) {
                    if (this[i] === obj) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            //Basic idea from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790442/test-if-an-element-can-contain-text
            function canContainText(node) {
                if(node.nodeType == 1) { //is an element node
                    return !voidNodeTags.contains(node.nodeName);
                } else { //is not an element node
                    return false;
                }
            };

            function getLastChildElement(el){
                var lc = el.lastChild;
                while(lc && lc.nodeType != 1) {
                    if(lc.previousSibling)
                        lc = lc.previousSibling;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                return lc;
            }

            //Based on Nico Burns's answer
            cursorManager.setEndOfContenteditable = function(contentEditableElement)
            {

                while(getLastChildElement(contentEditableElement) &&
                    canContainText(getLastChildElement(contentEditableElement))) {
                    contentEditableElement = getLastChildElement(contentEditableElement);
                }

                var range,selection;
                if(document.createRange)//Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
                {    
                    range = document.createRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
                    range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
                    range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
                    selection = window.getSelection();//get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
                    selection.removeAllRanges();//remove any selections already made
                    selection.addRange(range);//make the range you have just created the visible selection
                }
                else if(document.selection)//IE 8 and lower
                { 
                    range = document.body.createTextRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
                    range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
                    range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
                    range.select();//Select the range (make it the visible selection
                }
            }

}( window.cursorManager = window.cursorManager || {}));
```

Hopefully this works like what you want.