# How to display part of the text as bold in Angular

Tags: html, angular

This Question seems to be simple but involves some working...

I am using `Angular 15`.

I want display this text 'Subscriber Groups (2)' in a textbox in Angular HTML. Where the brackets and value should be bold and Subscriber Groups should be normal text and this value 2 can be any value that comes from Angular TS file.

The output should be as below..

Subscriber Groups **(10)**

```
<input id="Subscribers"  
    [value]="inputValue()"
    type="text" 
    readonly maxlength="40" class="form-control">
```

And the TS file contains like this..

```
inputValue() {
    const textBox = document.getElementById('subscribergroupscount') as HTMLInputElement;
    textBox.value = 'Subscriber Groups (' + selectedSubscriber.toString() + ')';
}
```

How can we do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Assuming the number and label are different you can wrap each in their own element but can't help without seeing your setup

Comment: You're saying the question seems to be simple, but is it not just a matter of doing `Subscriber Groups <strong>({{variable}})</strong>`? Please explain where the complexity lies.

Comment: We can't apply `HTML` to the `textbox`. That would not work. Updated the Question...

Comment: So why does it need to be a textbox? Input elements are for gathering input, not for displaying output.

Comment: That is the requirement...

Comment: So someone gave you a requirement saying that they want to display formatted output in an HTML `input` element? That doesn't make one iota of sense.

Comment: I think, there should be a workaround for this.

Comment: If you're asking how to format the value of a standard HTML input element, then the answer is "not possible". If not, you need to clarify your requirements. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10839279/how-do-you-make-just-some-text-inside-an-input-text-field-bold).

Comment: Thank you. We are able to conclude something. I will clarify the requirements once again.

Comment: You can create input like div using CSS and show it

Comment: The most closer I've saw is this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66899473/highlight-specific-words-in-textarea-angular-8)

Comment: If you want that you should consider programming your own input field. Im pretty sure there is nothing exsisting that fulfills your requirement